# wants to concatenate "@" with state in react native

Tags: react-native

hi every one i want to concatenate "@" with my state ..i want this sign in my text box with name same as instagram comment reply..but when i trying to concatenate with my state it only gives me "@ " sign in my text box 
here is my code of function where i am trying to concatenate

```
 PostReply(property){


 let showChar=`"@"`+`${this.state.showUserName}`
 this.setState({showreplyWithChar:showChar})
 }
```

and in my render functiom

```
            <Input placeholder='Add a Comment' value= 
        {this.state.showreplyWithChar} style={{}} onChangeText= 
       {(text)=>this.updatevalue(text)}/>
```

any suggetions from you people ?thanks

Comment: What `updatevalue(...)` do, can you share some code, also when you are calling `PostReply `?

Comment: update value get text when u type something in input field..in this scenerio i dont need updatevalue(..) function...